# Crawling Websites and capture different response status codes using Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, response

Can somebody help me out in understanding the response status code capture for every crawl request made my Scrapy Spider. I was able to get the output for Resp code 200 but if the website has 404 error it's not writing any output including 301 and 302 also.

Here is the code that i have implemented for someother website, and added a domain name containing my name for reference.

```
import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider



class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'TestSpider' 
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    resp_log_file = 'C:\\resp'
    ok_log_file = 'C:\\alright'
    bad_log_file = 'C:\\badresp'
    redirect_log_file = 'C:\\redirect'

    allowed_domains = ['santhosh.com']
    start_urls = ['santhosh.com/']

    # This spider has one rule: extract all (unique and canonicalized) links, follow them and parse them using the parse_items method
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                canonicalize=True,
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback="parse_item"
        )
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # The list of items that are found on the particular page
        items = []
        res = Selector(response)
        self.append(self.resp_log_file, str(response))
        # Only extract canonicalized and unique links (with respect to the current page)
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)
        try:
            if response.status == 404:
                ## 404 tracciate anche separatamente
                self.append(self.bad_log_file, response.url)
            elif response.status == 200:
                ## printa su ok_log_file
                self.append(self.ok_log_file, response.url)
            elif response.status == 302:
                ## printa su ok_log_file
                self.append(self.redirect_log_file, response.url)
            else:
                self.append(self.bad_log_file, response.url)
        except Exception, e:
            pass

        return None


    def append(self, file, string):
        print " Writing content to File "
        file = open(file, 'a')
        file.write(string+"\n")
        file.close()
```

I have seen questions related to response code capture but they were not exactly similar to my requests and hence created this new post. If there is any question available already related to this i request you to ignore this and redirect me over there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: wikipedia: [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: `200` = "get page without problem", `404` = "page not found", `30x` = "redirect because XXX".  If scrapy can't read page (ie. `404`) then it doesn't call parser.

Comment: don't use `except Exception, e: pass` because you may have unexpected error and you don't know it. Atleast display it `except Exception, e: print("ERROR:", e)`

Comment: I tried code and I see it sends `404` and `301` to `parse`, not to `parse_item`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried code and I see it sends `404` and `301` to `parse()`, not to `parse_item()` but I don't have page with broken links so it doesn't start `LinkExtractor`

I used portal [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/) to generate pages with different status.

Maybe if I have page with broken urls then `LinkExtractor` could run and I could get different results.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
#from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'MySpider' 

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 301, 302, 303]

    all_responses_log = './responses_all.log'
    ok_responses_log  = './responses_ok.log'
    bad_responses_log = './responses_bad.log'
    redirects_responses_log = './responses_redirect.log'

    start_urls = [
        'http://httpbin.org/status/301',
        'http://httpbin.org/status/302',
        'http://httpbin.org/status/303',

        'http://httpbin.org/status/404',
        'http://httpbin.org/status/200',
    ]

    # This spider has one rule: extract all (unique and canonicalized) links, follow them and parse them using the parse_items method
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                canonicalize=True,
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback="parse_item"
        )
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print('parse url:', response.url)

        self.test_status('parse()', response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('parse item url:', response.url)

        self.test_status('parse_item()', response)

        # The list of items that are found on the particular page
        items = []
        res = Selector(response)
        self.append(self.resp_log_file, str(response))
        # Only extract canonicalized and unique links (with respect to the current page)
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)

    def test_status(self, text, response):
        try:
            if response.status == 404:
                log = self.bad_responses_log
            elif response.status == 200:
                log = self.ok_responses_log
            #elif 299 < response.status < 400:
            elif response.status in (301, 302, 303, 307):
                log = self.redirects_responses_log
            else:
                log = self.redirects_responses_log

            message = "{} | {} | {}\n".format(response.status, text, response.url)
            self.append(log, message)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error:', e)

    def append(self, filename, string):
        print('Writing log:', filename)
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(string)


# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response @furas! I have tried the code and i could see that, it's just capturing the final status code among the codes that were handled. I have tried removing 3XX codes and it's capturing only 200 status in respective file.  I would request you to help me out if we can use the spider.Spider  or CrawlerSpider and use the same approach with additional advise for sub pages( links) follow through. I have used (http://httpbin.org) which has links in its page source.

Comment: Along with the above, is there a way to process the file containing domains by passing that as an argument to the Crawler using CrawlSpider to process their sub pages as well using LinkExtractor ?